# New SO/SE redesign does not "quieten" answers with worse than -3 net DV's

Tags: bug

I have noticed a change with the [new-look SO/SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107175/232251) that I wasn't expecting. It used to be the case that answers with >= three DVs (net) would be "quietened", faded out. I have always thought this sent a useful signal about the value of those answers.

It appears that [this is no longer the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107175/232251) (example thread linked - just scroll up/down at the -3 DV watershed). Is there any chance that this visual signal could be restored in the new design?